# WordPress site not showing some images

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have been trying for 2 days to fix this issue. I was just hired as a web dev at this company that already has a working website : [site](http://www.fotodiscountworld.co.za)

They asked me to fix a couple of things, which I did, however this one is quite annoying.

So the issue is that all the images are uploaded as products in woocomerce, and the site generates the product page.

Yet, after the wp update some of my images are not showing up and reuploading fixes the problem temporarily then it happens again.

This is an example of what happens :[here](https://www.fotodiscountworld.co.za/shop/nikon-en-el15a-rechargeable-li-ion-battery-d7500-free-delivery/)

I did:

- ftp and the images are there
- check css, nothing seems wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The image is returning an 404:**
[image]

The image is not present within the given folder. You should probably discuss with your coworkers why this file could be missing from the folder and if there is a backup or not.

Comment: hi yea thats what i thought as well. then i used ftp to go to the server itself and i found the image in the same directory. thanks though

Comment: Can you paste the exact path of the place where you found the image(in your FTP)?

Comment: do you think the dimensions in the title can be the issue?

Comment: the images with suffix `100x87` is cropped images. and the image `MH-26.jpg` is not the same as `MH-26-100x87.jpg`. if in the folder not exists the image with exact same name as in the request, you'll get 404

Comment: @ruanviviers I'm sure that that is the problem. You apparently don't have the original size image on your webserver, within the HTML the original image is the one being asked for.

Comment: thanks  that seems to be the issue i still have no idea how this came to be probably the image compression plugin. but this Set me on the right path !

Comment: Perhaps the image compression plugin you are using has the option enabled that removes the original version of the image after compressing it?